# TypeScript - TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"str1" | "str2"'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that, can accept only two possible values (for validation). For this I do:

```
interface PossibleValues {
    key: "str1" | "str2";
}
```

I can call the function with a **string** type only. This is by our architectural design and I have to deal with it.

```
set({key: type})
```

Because `type` is **string** and `key` can accept only `"str1" | "str2"` it says:
**TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"str1" | "str2"'** which makes sense.

The question is how to overcome this in a most elegant way? I mean I want to pass a **string** but the function call should fail if the string is not one of the two `"str1" | "str2"`

What I tried to do is:
`set({key: type} as PossibleValues)` and it stopped complaining but the desired behavior is not achieved. If I pass "str333" for example it still works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You need to realize that TypeScript is only there to help you with compile time errors. It does not do anything with runtime because it's compiled to JavaScript. Types and interfaces don't exist.

That being said, unless you are hard-coding strings to pass to this function that is `str1 | str2`, you shouldn't be relying on TypeScript types to make sure it works.

You need to code a JavaScript check and allow any string to be passed to the function.

You can create a type guard to achieve this effect.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

```
function isKey(value: string): value is "str1" | "str2" {
  return value === "str1" || value === "str2";
}
```

Then, you can use it to tell TypeScript you've checked the type.

```
if(isKey(type)) {
   set({ key: type }); // typescript won't complain anymore because you did a type check
}
```

Comment: I agree with @Todd although I think this kind of checking should be part of set() function itself

Answer (score 1):

You need to type the variable you've named `type` with that specific union type.

```
type PossibleValue = 'str1' | 'str2'

interface MyInterface {
    key: PossibleValue
    // ...
}

const set = (data: MyInterface) => { /* ... */ }

let type: PossibleValue = 'str1' // OK
type = 'str2' // OK
type = 'str3' // Type '"str3"' is not assignable to type 'PossibleValue'.

set({ key: type }) // OK
set({ key: 'str3' }) // Type '"str3"' is not assignable to type 'PossibleValue'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIDUCG6Cu0AvFAOQLABOAjKVAD5kWUBMpAUO8gHbASUAzHAGNoAWRABJXvyGioAb3ZQVUANYQQALliIUGbHkLLVAelNQAdNfYBfTsLjcKUBBGBQSACgAmOYDg6EtJ8giIQAJSeAHyKUKYAVFbWUAkW9uyYHqCQOvBIaJi4BMRMVLTxFgDyANLsOaXkVGyVULX14I3MAMx05lAAKp1kAEQ9I3TICFDccB44BQDm3DgGUMBw68Ok+fpFRhCklpxuwF4K6po6DVC2Uf3tp+eX2mWUvbf3FkOQo+OT01m8yWKzWGy2vx2ekKhhKR3YQA)

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to Todd Skelton's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63731278/12489423), if you are using Typescript 3.4+ you can define your type guard using the following syntax:

```
const keys = ['str1', 'str2'] as const
type Key = typeof keys[number]
const isKey = (s: string): s is Key => keys.some((k) => k === s)
```

The benefit of this approach is that you only need to modify the `keys` array if you ever want to add/remove possible values.